# Return records if all conditions Match

Tags: t-sql

I need a query to return records if all conditions Match.

**Example:**

Lets say I have a User “`John`” (`UserID: '37'`) that belongs to groups '`A`','`B`','`C`' (`GroupID: '47', '48', '166'`)

And I type

```
Select person, group
from persons p inner join groups g
on p.id = g.id

where p.id = '37'
  and g.id in ('47','166')
```

The query should return **No Record** because not all conditions match, Group '`C`' was not part of the query.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to find people who membership is exactly the two groups you list, no more no less.?

Comment: From your sample ids it's clear that you can't really want `p.id = g.id`. There's another piece missing here.

Comment: Does the groups table have a field is a reference to the UserID? Or is there another table that has the relation from the person table to the group table? Also do you mean group "B" was not part of the query?  Give of sample data and table structures and what you expect the results to be.

Comment: Show some effort the query you posted would return no records. Way to many id going around.

Comment: your example does not make sense... do you really join the p.id to the g.id -- shouldn't it be p.id to g.userID or g.personid

Comment: To shawnt001, Return the exact selection no more no less. The above query will return records because p.id has membership in '47','48','166'

Comment: The relationship should be p.id = g.userid

Answer (score 1):

This has to be a dup but I cannot find it

```
Select p.id
from persons p inner join groups g
on p.id = g.UserID
where p.id = '37'
  and g.GroupID in ('47','166') 
group by person 
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: "1 Answer" returns '47', it should not return any records, since not all conditions were true. I have no idea how to do this!

Comment: Right now what you have is not even valid syntax so is returns nothing.

Comment: It would have to be something like this: Select p.id
from persons p inner join groups g
on p.id = g.UserID
where p.id = '37'

Comment: Select p.id, g.UserID
from persons p inner join groups g
on p.id = g.UserID
where p.id = '37'

This returns
ID      UserID
37     47
37     48
37     166

Then there needs to be a check for all records and match to criteria

Comment: So then you did not even try my answer.

Comment: I tried the answer and returns a value '47'. it should not return any value since not all conditions were met

Comment: I don't know what 'all' is?   If you cannot articulate a question I cannot help.  Really returns 37 47 37 48 37 166 is supposed to mean something.   Are you like 12 years old?

Comment: Lets say I have a User “John” (UserID: '37') that belongs to groups 'A','B','C' (GroupID: A='47',B= '48',C= '166') - that was part of the example above. The format of comments make it hard to illustrate

Comment: Then why is what you posted and g.id in ('47','166').  Figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

--The subquery did what I was after

SELECT p.id, g.id

FROM persons p inner join groups g 
on p.id = g.Userid

where g.Userid = 
             (select Userid from groups gs
                where p.id = gs.Userid
                 And gs.id in (47,166)
                    group by g.Userid
                     having count(distinct gs.id) = 3)